# Problem with applying focus effect on label in css

Tags: css

I'm following a tutorial from Online Tutorials about moving placeholder. And i have problem. In his tutorial css code is like this:

```
.wrapper input:focus ~ label {
    top: -12px;
}
```

But when i write this in my css code label doesn't move at all. Is this ~ deprecated in CSS3 or what?
And how i have to do this then.

Comment: Is your `label` in the DOM after the `input`? If so, add `position: relative`.

Comment: Thanks! moving label after input helped :) Before i had it before input